# How to pass data from table of records to Modal for editing purposes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I know this has been asked a lot but I haven't found any of the answers to the issue to be very fruitful. I essentially have a table inside a view that is displayed using a foreach loop in PHP, this spits out the records one by one and appends some 'Action' buttons in the last column (download, delete and edit). The download and delete functions work perfectly, I just pass the ID in from each record in the foreach loop, job done.

I'm having a lot of issues with my modal though, it only ever displays the data from the first record when I echo the data in the 'value' field of each input. I'm really stumped on how to make this functionality work (JQuery is not my strongest language). I've seen some responses talking about Ajax, but I'd rather not use Ajax in this project. I'm using the codeigniter framework also for some more info.

I think the issue is that the modal is only created once when the foreach loop starts running, hence why it only ever has the first record data inside the modal, any help to get around this so I can edit each individual record inside the table would be great! Thanks for the help.

HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="container" id="widecontainer">
  <h1 id="title">VMS Failure Records</h1>
  <br>
<!-- print table with results onto view.php -->
<table class="table table-bordered" id="record">
<?php if($results) : ?>
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #d3d3d3;">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>VSM S/N</th>
      <th>VM S/N</th>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Install Loc</th>
      <th>Observed During</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Reported By</th>
      <th>Replaced With</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Failure Classification</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- foreach result place it in row in table -->
<?php foreach($results as $res) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['vsm_sn'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['vm_sn'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['project'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['site'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['install_location'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['observed_during'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['comments'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['reported_by'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['replaced_with'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['date'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $res['classification'] ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo form_open('/pages/delete/'. $res['id']); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete_btn" id="delete_btn" target="#confirmation">
              <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>

            <!-- Modal displays when user clicks delete, asking them to confirm the deletion -->
            <div id="confirm" name="confirm" class="modal fade">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Record <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p style="color: red;"><strong>Deleting this record will delete .PDF and QRCode Data.</strong></p>
                  <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</button>
                  <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </form>


          <!--Modal displays to allow user to download the selected record. -->
          <?php echo form_open('/pages/downloadFile/'. $res['id']); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" alt="Download .pdf">
              <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </form>

          <form>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success update_btn" id="update_btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
            vsm-sn="<?php echo $res['vsm_sn'];?>" record-id="<?php echo $res['id']; ?>">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </form>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Record</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="profileForm">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="">
           VSM SN : <input class="form-control" name="vsm_sn" value="" placeholder="VSM SN">
           </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        </td>
      </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- If there are no results, display table headings and message -->
<?php elseif(!$results) : ?>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>VSM S/N</th>
      <th>VM S/N</th>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Install Loc</th>
      <th>Observed During</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Reported By</th>
      <th>Replaced With</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Failure Classification</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <h3 style="color: red;">No Results to Display</h3>
</tbody>
<?php endif; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // get information to update quickly to modal view as loading begins
  var opener=e.relatedTarget;//this holds the element who called the modal

   //we get details from attributes
  var vsm_sn=$(opener).attr('vsm-sn');

//set what we got to our form
  $('#profileForm').find('[name="vsm_sn"]').val(vsm_sn);
});
```

Comment: are you trying to pass the user information from each array to modal and then the modal displays it for each of the row button clicked?

Comment: Well not user data, the data that is looped into the table. So Yes Theo that is right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to go about it , is to use events hooks which is tied to the modal to help manage dynamism on modals.

Take for example, you want to pass information from the for loop to the modal you can do this using just a modal and then update the modal as it opens.

check bootstrap docs you will see this hook for modal
**show.bs.modal**

we then use attributes from the button to pick out our information we are going to display on the modal, e.g

`<button user-id="<?php echo $data[$i]->userID; ?>" first-name="<?php echo $data[$i]->firstname;?>">Edit</button>`

then we can use Jquery to pick it up and hook it when the modal is opening

See for example code here, replace the static repeat with your dynamic coding

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // get information to update quickly to modal view as loading begins
  var opener=e.relatedTarget;//this holds the element who called the modal
   
   //we get details from attributes
  var firstname=$(opener).attr('first-name');

//set what we got to our form
  $('#profileForm').find('[name="firstname"]').val(firstname);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>SN</th>
   <th>Firstname</th>
   <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Theophilus</td>
   <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" first-name="Theophilus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Edit
    </button>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Omoregbee</td>
   <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" first-name="Omoregbee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Edit
    </button>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Endurance</td>
   <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" first-name="Endurance" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Edit
    </button>
   </td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="profileForm">
       Firstname : <input class="form-control" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="firstname">
       </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Run it and see the result, so you can change the table style to use loop in php and then echo your data as attribute.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm away from my desk in work at the moment. I will try it when I get back! Looking at the code you have there it is EXCATLY what I want it to do. Thank you
!

Comment: Hey I tried this in the context of my code, but no values are placed into the modal when I click on the edit button, I have replaced my code at the top with the full code incase there is anything that you can see that may be preventing it from working. Thanks again

Comment: I fixed it!! I played around with the button and it seemed to have fixed it, the field in the modal is now populated with the correct value for each row, cheers dude.

Answer (score 0):

assign an id to modal body, e.g. : modal-body

declare a variable to store the HTML for the modal body, e.g. var modalHTML = ''

then append the contents in the for loop to that variable.

after that append the variable to the modal body, using $('#modal-body).append($(modalHTML)).